# What is the save DC of a supernatural ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, saving-throw

I am playing as a oracle who has the supernatural ability Brain Drain. It says that the target gets to make a Will save. What is the DC of this Will save? Normally a Will save's DC is 10 + spell level + ability modifier, but since it is a supernatural ability what do I add for spell level?

Answer (score 11):

[PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle#TOC-Revelation):

> ...the DC to save against these revelations is equal to 10 + 1/2 the oracle’s level + the oracle’s Charisma modifier.

Because the revelation is a supernatural ability, not a spell or spell-like ability, spell level doesn't apply.  If another effect needs to refer to spell level for some reason (it happens very rarely), a suggested houserule is to use the highest level spell you could cast at the earliest level you can get the supernatural ability (for brain drain, this would make it effectively first level).

Comment: I think just using half your oracle level works as well for the “level” of the supernatural abilities; allowing it to grow with you isn’t a bad idea, and it’s far easier to keep track of. Though really, *nothing* should ever be looking for that number; when does that happen?

Comment: @KRyan You mean, "When does a supernatural ability look for a spell level when that spell level isn't provided, forcing the DM has to compare it to existing spells and make an *ad hoc* ruling?" All. The. Damn. Time. *Sigh.* (Or did you mean something else?)

Comment: @KRyan when you have opposing magics interact, it virtually always either goes to a caster level check or one effect will check the other's spell level.  There's a part in the FAQ where a dev (Mr. Jacobs?  I can't recall) goes off on a tangent complaining about how many times he begged to have these things assigned spell levels.  It's more often done with SLAs that don't directly map to actual spells, though, like some sorcerer bloodline powers.  They're SLAs with no spell level, and he suggests the rule I suggested there.

Answer (score 1):

> #### Mysteries
>
> Each oracle must choose from among the following mysteries. Unless otherwise noted, the DC to save against these revelations is equal to 10 + 1/2 the oracle's level + the oracle's Charisma modifier. Spells marked with an asterisk (*) appear in Chapter 5 of this book

Answer (score 1):

The DC for a supernatural ability is usually 10 + 1/2 the class level (or racial HD) + an ability score modifier. The specific DC should be listed under the class, feat, creature description, or universal monster rule that grants the ability.

For an oracle revelation, the DC is 10 + 1/2 your oracle level + your Charisma modifier as noted under the revelation class feature.